# How to give ec2 instance access to s3 using boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, boto3, amazon-iam

By googling, I found [this tutorial on accessing S3 from EC2 instance without credential file](http://parthicloud.com/how-to-access-s3-bucket-from-application-on-amazon-ec2-without-access-credentials/). I followed its instructions and got the desired instance. The aws web console page looks like 
[image]

However, I don't want to do it manually using the web console every time. How can I create such EC2 instances using boto3?

I tried

```
s = boto3.Session(profile_name='dev', region_name='us-east-1')
ec2 = s.resource('ec2')
rc = ec2.create_instances(ImageId='ami-0e297018', 
                          InstanceType='t2.nano',
                          MinCount=1, 
                          MaxCount=1, 
                          KeyName='my-key', 
                          IamInstanceProfile={'Name': 'harness-worker'},
                          )
```

where `harness-worker` is the IAM role with access to S3, but nothing else.
It is also used in the first approach with the aws web console tutorial.

Then I got error saying

> ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling
>   the RunInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this
>   operation.

Did I do something obviously wrong?

The `dev` profile has AmazonEC2FullAccess. Without the line `IamInstanceProfile={'Name': 'harness-worker'},`, `create_instances` is able to create instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To assign an IAMProfile to an instance, `AmazonEC2FullAccess` is not sufficient. In addition, you need the following privilege to pass the role to the instance.

See: [Granting an IAM User Permission to Pass an IAM Role to an Instance](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/iam-roles-for-amazon-ec2.html#permission-to-pass-iam-roles)

```
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "iam:PassRole",
  "Resource": "*"
}
```

First you can give full IAM access to your `dev` profile and see it works. Then remove full IAM access and give only `iam:PassRole` and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with the role you are trying to assign the new EC2 instance. The Python script you are running doesn't have the RunInstances permission.

Comment: Sorry I am new to boto3 and aws. Could you explain a bit more on how to fix it? Thank you.

Comment: You have some sort if IAM credentials that your python script is using to interface with the AWS API. Those credentials dont have permission to create new EC2 instances. This is not an issue with your code. It is an issue with the IAM account or profile that you are uaing.

Comment: The dev profile has AmazonEC2FullAccess. Without the line IamInstanceProfile={'Name': 'harness-worker'},, create_instances is able to create instance.